# Use FastReport.Net without database

Tags: c#, sqlite, fastreport

I want use FastReport.net with a SQLite database. I added `fastreport.sqlite.dll` to designer, but I was unable to use SQLite in extra connections folder (I had an error).

Is it possible to send the data source from code to the report?

Comment: What was the error you got when adding the connection to your database? You should be specific, and completely describe your problem.

Comment: I edited your question. Sorry, it changed a lot! But it was unclear before the change. Modify it if you need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible to send a data source to the report from code. Here is what you should do:

```
public static void ShowDesign(IEnumerable data = null)
{
    var r = GetLoadedReport();
    if (data != null)
    {
        RegisterData(r, data);
    }
    r.Design();
}

public static void PreviewPrint(IEnumerable data)
{
    var r = GetLoadedReport();
    RegisterData(r, data);
    r.Show();
}

private static void RegisterData(Report r, IEnumerable data)
{
    r.RegisterData(data, "list");
    r.GetDataSource("list").Enabled = true;
}

public static Report GetLoadedReport()
{
    return Report.FromFile(GetReportFilePath());
}

public static string GetReportFilePath()
{
    // return the report file path (.frx file)
}
```

You can call `ShowDesign` to show the report designer or `PreviewPrint` to print the report. And you see how I am passing the data source to the report.